RESTful API accepting multiple POSTS as a batch
I'm building a RESTful API to create a new customer POST /customers.  This works well for creating customers on a per transaction basis. However a new scenario has come to light whereby the recent system will need to process the output as a batch file. Given the volumes it won't be practical to pass all records in a single POST operation.
Looking at how to resolve this, I could either introduce a Container Object e.g. POST /customerbatch and then add customers to a parent container using the batch id as a linking entity; or perhaps have an attribute of the customer object such as "multi-part". Ideally the POST /customers API should operate as a single transaction or accept a batch of records.
Recognising there's probably a pattern to this, would appreciate a pointer in the right direction.

When people talk about a 'batch' endpoint in the context of a rest-ish API, typically that does mean 'passing all records in a single HTTP request (which is perhaps POST)'. If it's not that, it's probably not a batch request and you just want multiple individual HTTP requests in sequence?

the key aspect to the requirement is the option for the calling service to specify which records need to be appended to each other. On one occasion a single transaction may be processed in isolation and in another scenario 100 customers may need to be batched together and processed together.

Got it, so I guess you are looking for a series of requests that start a transaction, add operations to it and then finally commit or roll it back. Sounds reasonable. If this question was explicitly looking for prior art or some public API that already does this, I don't have an example but treating the whole transaction as just another (collection) resource sounds like a reasonable design for this.

Having done some further research one potential option would be to have the POST /customers response return a group id. Then on subsequent POSTS include a group id which would instruct the API to allocate that transaction to the group id specified and build up a batch.
Triggering the batch may then look something like POST /customers/{groupid} vs. POST /customers/{id} which would process a single record.
